# Blank sed output after substitution using -n

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, grep

probably simple question for someone who knows, but I'm having a hard time retrieving some variable values from a file. My file is something like:

```
variable1 12
variable2 43
variable3 897
```

and I want to get the value of variable2, 43.

I tried some commands with sed but with no luck:

```
sed -n 's/variable2 //;s/variable3//' myFile
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With **only** `sed`:

```
$ sed -n 's/^variable2 //p' file
43
```

Your problem is you are using `-n` to suppress the output of `sed` so you need the `p` flag so `sed` prints the lines where the substitution took place.

As this just pattern matching I would go with **only** grep for this:

```
$ cat file
variable1 12
variable2 43
variable3 897

$ grep -Po '(?<=^variable2 )\d+' file
43
```

Or even just `awk`:

```
$ awk '$1=="variable2"/{print $2}' file
43
```

Comment: While I love `grep -Po`, I rarely recommend it because it's not very portable.  **+1** for your `sed` solution, though.

Comment: @ghoti I would say the very high majority Linux and OSX come with `GNU sed`, where is not supported out of curiosity?

Comment: GNU/Linux systems usually come with GNU sed, but OSX, FreeBSD, Solaris, HP/UX, etc all have their own.  Well, OSX's sed is derived from FreeBSD's, and Solaris came with both a SysV and a BSD sed until version 11.  But your sed solution is fine, and portable.  It's grep's `-P` option that is not, in FreeBSD, or any of the others except OSX, which started supporting it in version 10.6.  It certainly isn't universal.

Comment: And your `awk` solution fails if the file includes a `variable20`.  When looking for a fixed string, best to test for a fixed string.  `awk '$1=="variable2"{print $2}'`  Or what [pepoluan posted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14261023/1072112), as it provides better flexibility.

Answer (score 3):

Must you use `sed`?

I prefer using `awk` for this kind of stuff:

```
awk -v varname="variable2" '$1==varname {print $2}' myFile
```

This will work as long as there are no variables (in the left column) that contains a space.

***Edit:***

Since the title is "Get variable value from file with bash", here's a version that does not involve an external program

```
wantvar="variable2"
datafile="myFile"
while read varname varval; do
  # Case-insensitive matching. If you need case-sensitivity, remove the pair of commas
  # on both sides.
  if [[ ${varname,,} = ${wantvar,,} ]]; then
    echo $varval
    break
  fi
done < $datafile
```

Comment: There is no benefit in passing `varname` if you do the assignment inline might as well be `awk '$1=="variable2"{print $2}' file` plus say away from bash for things like this.

Comment: @sudo_O true. Just in case the question-maker wants to embed that line in a script somewhere. As to your second statement, the **title** of the question is "... with bash". I wrote the script to prevent the question-maker from doing something totally unnecessary like `some_variable="$(awk ....)"`

Comment: Don't get hung up on title, I have changed it to reflect the question, the OP just missed the `p` flag to `sed`. Really bash is not suited to this kind of thing!

Answer (score 2):

Use [grep](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) to find the line and then use [cut](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cut) to extract the value:

```
$ grep ^variable2 myFile | cut -d ' ' -f 2
```

Test:

```
$ cat myFile 
variable1 12
variable2 43
variable3 897
$ grep ^variable2 myFile | cut -d ' ' -f 2
43
$
```

Answer (score 1):

For a file formatted like that, a grep|awk will work:

```
grep variable2 file | awk '{print $2}'
```

Don't count on it for files formatted even slightly differently.

Comment: This is redundant, there's no need to pipe from grep to awk.  See [pepoluan's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14261023/1072112).

Comment: Or see mine.. Either use `grep` or `awk` both is 1 process to many.